# imDbPy Example not working: 'key error'

Tags: python, python-3.6, imdbpy

I copied the example from the imDbPy page.

```
# Create the object that will be used to access the IMDb's database.
ia = imdb.IMDb() # by default access the web.

# Search for a movie (get a list of Movie objects).
s_result = ia.search_movie('The Untouchables')

# Print the long imdb canonical title and movieID of the results.
for item in s_result:
   print(item['long imdb canonical title'], item.movieID)

# Retrieves default information for the first result (a Movie object).
the_unt = s_result[0]
ia.update(the_unt)

# Print some information.
print(the_unt['runtime'])
print(the_unt['rating'])
director = the_unt['director'] # get a list of Person objects.
```

I now get this key error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Artificial Intelligence\Machine Learning\movie_classification.py", line 76, in <module>
    print(the_unt['runtime'])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\imdb\utils.py", line 1467, in __getitem__
    rawData = self.data[key]
KeyError: 'runtimes'
[Finished in 3.6s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Artificial Intelligence\Machine Learning\movie_classification.py"]
[dir: C:\Artificial Intelligence\Machine Learning]
[path: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\libnvvp;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Users\lordp\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]
```

From what I understand it says that 'runtimes' doesn't exist as a key.

The keys that i can use are these (the_unt.keys()):

```
['title', 'kind', 'year', 'akas', 'plot', 'canonical title', 'long imdb title', 'long imdb canonical title', 'smart canonical title', 'smart long imdb canonical title']
```

But from what the internet says I should have many more options.

I installed imDbPy correctly as far as I know.
Does anyone know the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, a recent change in the web pages of the IMDb site has broken most of IMDbPY.  See this discussion: https://github.com/alberanid/imdbpy/issues/103

Unfortunately there's not much you can do, beside using the (few) data available from http://www.imdb.com/interfaces/